# Disable alternating table row colors

Tags: html, css

I added this css rule `tr  { background-color:transparent; }` to make all my rows have transparent backgrounds, but for some reason the even rows are still light blue.  I looked in the chrome debugger and the rule is active, but checking/unchecking it doesn't affect the color. The odd rows change colors fine. What's going on here?

Comment: You have some code somewhere changing the color. Remove it..

Comment: I'm not positive about this but I think if the CSS rule is active in the chrome debugger it means it wasn't overwritten. If it was overwritten it would be struck through. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I added this line following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial.

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
```

I deleted it and now its working.

Answer (score 2):

Transparent is the default value of background-color if you do not set one. It just lets the element inherit the color/background from its parent. You should override the even rows with a solid color.

However, with what you described, we cannot tell what other colors are in the table. You only mentioned light blue for the even rows.

Comment: I've tried other colors like tr  { background-color:white; }
and tr  { background-color:blue; } as well. Each time, only the odd rows change colors.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is check where and how the even rows are assigned a class/color to differentiate them. Then remove it. Trying to override it instead is pretty bad.